# Reading a raw HTTP request in Django 1.3

Tags: python, django, http

I want to read a raw HTTP request in Django 1.3.

Is there an easy way to do it?

I tried the following without success:

```
clength = int(request.META.get("CONTENT_LENGTH"))
data = request.read(1000)
# data comes out empty
```

Also tried:

```
for part in request:
    pass
    # never enters the loop
```

The reason I am doing this is because somehow my `raw_post_data` attribute is empty when using `multipart/related` MIME information on the `POST` command. Apparently is a [bug that's been there for a long time](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9054).

Comment: `request` doesn't have any content. It just has details on the request being made -- hence the name. The content comes in with the *response*.

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Is this trying to parse uploaded file contents?

Comment: @jathanism: no. I am receiving a `multipart/related` POST from a MMS Message Center and, even though the data is there, DJANGO doesn't expose it through `request` object. I made sure the data is there by sniffing the packets.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: posted data should be in the `response` object?

Comment: Yep, looks like it's a bug alright. I guess you should try the patch in that bug report and see if that works for you.

Comment: @jathanism: will try something like that. patch is too old. won't patch directly against 1.3 or 1.3.1. If I create a new patch, will try to submit it. Thanks!

Comment: I find raw content in `request.body` in Django REST Framework 3.

Answer (score 3):

For django version < 1.4, you can use `HttpRequest.raw_post_data`, and for version >= 1.4, using `HttpRequest.body` [instead](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried HttpRequest.raw_post_data? Looks like something you should take a look at until the bug is fixed.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.raw_post_data

Comment: Didn't realize the question what _that_ old... But it might be good info for some people, so I will just leave the answer.

Comment: thanks! I did look into HttpRequest.raw_post_data. It's set to `nil` at some part of the framework because of its header saying it's a `multipart/related` post...